# Method is undefined for type "subclassName"

Tags: java, class, inheritance, methods

I have three classes named Matrix, BasicOperations and Determinant in the same package.

I want to define separate methods in separate classes (for example, methods related to finding determinants under the Determinant class), but I get errors like "The method getValue(int, int) is undefined for the type Determinant" in lines 7 and 9 in the Determinant class.
I couldn't figure out where I made a mistake, so I had to ask, how can I make these methods work?

Matrix.java (for creating objects)

```
package Matrix;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Matrix {

    public int n;
    public int m;
    public ArrayList<Double> Matrices = new ArrayList<Double>();
    
    public Matrix(int n, int m) {
        
        this.n = n;
        this.m = m;
        
        Matrices = new ArrayList<Double>(n*m);
        
    }
}
```

BasicOperations.java (for containing basic operation methods)

```
package Matrix;
public class BasicOperations extends Matrix{

    public BasicOperations(int n, int m){
        super(n, m);
    }
    
    public void putTo(int a, int b, double value) {
        
        //allows user to put a value at coordinate ab in the matrix.
        int index = (a-1)*m + b - 1;
        Matrices.add(index, value);
        
    }

    public void changeValue(int a, int b, double newValue) {
        
        //allows user to replace the value at coordinate ab in the matrix with a new value.
        int index = (a-1)*m + b - 1;
        Matrices.remove(index);
        Matrices.add(index, newValue);
        
    }

    public void printValue(int a, int b) {
        
        //allows user to print the value at coordinate ab in the matrix.
        int index = (a-1)*m + b - 1;
        double element = Matrices.get(index);
        System.out.println("Bu matrisin "+a+". satır "+b+". sütunda bulunan elemanı "+element+" sayısıdır.");
        System.out.print("\n");
        
    }

    public double getValue(int a, int b) {
        
        //allows user to get the value at coordinate ab in the matrix.
        int index = (a-1)*m + b - 1;
        double value = Matrices.get(index);
        return value;
        
    }

    public void printMatrix() {
        
        //allows user to print the matrix.
        for(int a = 1; a <= n; a++) {
            System.out.print("[");
            for(int b = 1; b <= m; b++) {
                if(b == 1) {
                    System.out.print(Matrices.get((a-1)*m + b - 1).toString());
                } else {
                    System.out.print("  " +Matrices.get((a-1)*m + b - 1).toString());
                }
            }
            System.out.println("]");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        
    }

    public int getRowNumber() {
        
        //allows user to get number of rows.
        return n;
        
    }
    
    public int getColumnNumber() {
        
        //allows user to get number of columns.
        return m;
        
    }

}
```

Determinant.java (for containing determinant operation methods)

```
package Matrix;

class Determinant{
    
    public double get2x2Determinant() {
        
        if(this.getColumnNumber() * this.getRowNumber() == 4) {
            
            double det = (this.getValue(1, 1) * this.getValue(2, 2)) - (this.getValue(1, 2) * this.getValue(2, 1));
            return det;
            
        } else {
            
            return 0;
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: What's unclear about the error? You call `this.getValue()`, but there is no such method in the class you show. Since the class extends `Object` implicitly, there is no such method in the class hierarchy either. Either write the methods, or extend from the appropriate class.

Comment: @Chaosfire do you mean making the determinant class the subclass of basicoperations? but when in the same package, can't I use the public methods in every class?

Comment: Your OOP class structure is out of whack and is not how you do inheritance or Java. A determinant is, for example, a basic property of a matrix, and so should not be its own class but rather part of the Matrix class. You need to re-think your class structure using basic OOPs principles.

Comment: Regarding "*can't I use the public methods in every class?"* -- yes you can, but you have to call those methods on objects of type that actually has those methods. Determinant doesn't have these methods, and so `this.getValue(...)` is meaningless to the Java compiler in that class. You *could* have Determinant extend from Matrix, and the code would compile, but as I mentioned in my comment above, you shouldn't do this. Instead, give Matrix a `getDeterminant()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your direct problem stems from trying to call a method that doesn't exist for the class, `getValue(...)`. Yes, the method exits in the Matrix class and in all classes that extend from it, and is declared `public`, and so it can be called on any object that is a Matrix or a child of Matrix, but Determinant isn't the such a class as does not derive from the Matrix class, it has no parent class other than object.  And so when you call `this.getValue(...)` the compiler looks inside of the Determinant class and its parent, Object, sees that the method does not exist, and calls "foul".

One solution that is quick, easy and *wrong* would be to have Determinant extend from the Matrix or BasicOperations class, and then yes, it would have this method, but then you are stuck with a bad code design, an overly fragmented class. The Matrix class should truly hold all the states and behaviors of a mathematical matrix, and you are splitting it apart for no reason. This will only increase confusion, errors, and will give you no benefit. Instead, create a complete and full Matrix class. Divide out things that are not part of matrices, such as this: `public ArrayList<Double> Matrices = new ArrayList<Double>();`. This doesn't really belong inside of Matrix.

Other suggestions:

- The fields should all be private, for encapsulation purposes
- As mentioned above, don't artificially fragment your classes
- But also, don't put too much into your classes. Avoid creating so-called "god-classes".

e.g.,

```
public class Matrix {
    private double[][] elements;

    // most of this code is similar to your current code
    public Matrix(int rows, int columns) {
        this.elements = new double[rows][columns];
    }

    public Matrix(double[][] elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    public Matrix(Matrix matrix) {
        this.elements = matrix.elements;
    }

    public double getElement(int row, int column) {
        return this.elements[row][column];
    }

    public void setElement(int row, int column, double value) {
        this.elements[row][column] = value;
    }

    public int getRows() {
        return this.elements.length;
    }

    public int getColumns() {
        return this.elements[0].length;
    }

    public Matrix add(Matrix matrix) {
        // test first that row and column counts are the same. If not, throw exception
        // then do calculation
    }

    public Matrix subtract(Matrix matrix) {
        // test first that row and column counts are the same. If not, throw exception
        // then do calculation
    }

    public Matrix multiply(Matrix matrix) {
        // test first that row count of one matrix equals the  column counts of the other
        // then do calculation
    }

    // getSubMatric
    public Matrix getSubMatrix(int row, int column) {
        // ...
    }

    public double getDeterminant() {
        // check that row and column counts are not zero or one and that they are the same, that it is a square matrix
        // note that even square matrices sometimes have no valid determinant
    }

    public Matrix getTranspose() {
        //....
    }

    // print
    public void print() {
        for (double[] row : this.elements) {
            for (double element : row) {
                System.out.print(element + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```